# Justify at right margin or in next line also in longtable env

Tags: spacing, pdftex, longtable

Hello guys I'm using this command to get some text at the right side of a line:

```
\newcommand{\tright}[1]{%
  {\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill#1% hfil has been replaced with hfill to bring #1 close ti very end of the line once \par below has been eliminated
  \parfillskip=0pt\finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}
  }
```

When I use it in a basic article document in a normal environment it work ok

one \tright{two} 
one \tright{two} 
one \tright{two}

give me: 
[the dots stands for white spaces, I don't know how to insert large blank space in MD, thought <pre> tag would work but it does not and hate repeating "&nbsp;"]
one.................................................................... two 
one.................................................................... two 
one.................................................................... two

If I do the same in a longtable environment with 2 columns for example I get instead:

one.................................................................... two

one.................................................................... two

one.................................................................... two

A line in between each row appear because of the \par command, I could remove it to avoid this behavior but I need it to keep text in the far right margin in some extreme cases, does someone knows some tips to solve this ?

Comment: This look a lot like \leaderfill (Knuth, p. 223) except no \leaders.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that is working so far, I removed the "\penalty50" and deleted the final "\par"
this way it seems to behave the same in a longtable environment or a normal environment.
In some cases \par could be replaced with "\hfil\nobreak"
Hope it helps